# Oberserver and Observable implemented by the same class

Tags: oop, observer-pattern

Is it a good OO practice to implement Observer and Observable interface to the same class in cases like given below?
"News server application that notified if there are new news items. Then the subscribers of news categories get notified via the server when that happens"

Comment: If implementing both Observer and Observable interface to the same class is not good should I add separate classes to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are implementing the [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). You have a Composite Observer that receives events and then emits them to its children. Combining the Observer and Composite patterns is perfectly acceptable.